# Can't load local storage into text area

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to load a local storage variable called: "MyNewLocation" into a Form's text area.

```
<div class="kn-input kn-input-paragraph_text" id="kn-input-field_53"> 
<label for="field_53" class="knack-input-label"><span class="kn-input-label">Location</span></label>
<p class="kn-instructions" style="display: none;"></p>
<div class="input">
<textarea id="field_53" name="field_53"></textarea>
</div>  
</div>
```

My Javascript I'm using to retrieve the localStorage Variable is:

```
var MyNewLocation = document.querySelector("#field_53");
if (window.localStorage["MyNewLocation"]) {
MyNewLocation.value = window.localStorage["MyNewLocation"];
};
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kab35Lox/3/

Thanks so much.

Comment: Working fine http://jsfiddle.net/kab35Lox/4/

Comment: Is `.localStorage["MyNewLocation"]` supposed to be using the variable you got from querySelector()? If so, then `"MyStorageLocation"` and `MyStorageLocation` are two totally diffent things: string v.s. variable.

Comment: @RahilWazir Thanks for that. I see you set the localstorage in the javascript, however I have set that variable using another script. Is there any way to retrieve that the key value insead of setting it?

Comment: How do you determine what the key for lookup in localStorage is? Does the key match the field name?

Comment: @Moe It depends on whats the priority of your calling script when you set the value before trying retrieving it.

Comment: field_53.value=localStorage.MyNewLocation || ""; (but i don't see it being saved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing DOM objects with string values associated with those objects. You also do not clearly show how you derive the key to be used in localStorage lookup.  In my example, I will assume key name is same as input field id (field_53);

```
var MyNewLocation = document.querySelector("#field_53");
var locationKey = 'field_53';
var locationValue = window.localStorage.getItem(locationKey);
if (locationValue) {
    MyNewLocation.value = locationValue;
} else {
    console.log('Error retrieving key `' . locationKey . '` from localStorage');
}
```